# Значение корня "ра"

Tags: этимология, история

Правда ли, что слово "Ра" означало "солнце" не только в египетском языке, но является вообще чуть ли не общим индоевропейским корнем с тем же значением - отсюда старое название Волги - Ра и слово "радуга", а также "радость"?
Или это очередные новомодные измышления?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Честно говоря, надоело уже комментировать перлы Задорнова и Чудинова, но попробую.

Здесь как минимум две ошибки. "Египетcкий язык" - это нонсенс. Современные египтяне говорят на арабском (одном или даже нескольких из диалектов), в классический эллинско-римский период, очевидно, на латыни и греческом, а  до того - на древнеегипетском языке. Это во-первых. А во-вторых, язык этот не относился к индоевропейским. Во всяком случае генетические связи его весьма темны. Ни о какой общности с индоевропейскими речи идти не может. Ну и наконец, фонетическая реконструкция того языка возможна только до определенного предела. Египтологи более или менее уверенно говорят только о согласных звуках. Вокализмы расставлены просто с потолка, для удобства произношения.
Далее. "Ра" - название не Солнца, а бога. Название Ра в отношении Волги возникло не раньше римского периода, когда ни о каких древних египтянах с их богами речи уже не шло. 
Ну и т.д.

Радуга по наиболее распространённой версии действительно могло произойти от корня "рад", "ръдъ" (не "ра"), означавшего "весёлый", "благостый", но даже это не всеми признано. Остальное - ффтопку.

Comment: Ну, потомок древнеегипетского существует до сих пор - это коптский язык. Только там "солнце" - "рэ", а не "ра". Вполне возможно, что в древнеегипетском было так же, потому что мы так до сих пор и не знаем огласовки иероглифов - гласные-то не писались.

Answer (score 3):

Древнегипетское "Ра" обозначало верховного бога. В разные периоды эта приставка добавлялась к богу мудрости Тоту, богу солнечного света Атону и богу солнца Амону. Так как последнего почитали дольше всех, в массовой культуре XX-XXI вв. возникло убеждение, что Ра - одно из имён бога солнца, хотя это и не совсем так.

Лингвистами не найдено никакого существенного влияния древнеегипетского языка на индоевропейские языки, в том числе на русский. Звук [р] есть во многих языках и то, что он иногда встречается в словах, связанных с солнцем, -  не более чем совпадение.

Comment: Спасибо! Так я и знал, что присутствующее в 25 языках -Ra- в названиях Солнца не более, чем совпадение!